# How do you solve the error GlassFish Server 3.1.2 start failed in NetBeans IDE 7.1.1?

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, glassfish-3, netbeans-7

Change the port to 9999 domain.xml file and add the server again in Netbeans, but the error persists

Comment: Do you have a full error or stack trace or something?

Comment: Are you on Windows?  If so, where is glassfish installed?  If c:\program files, is, your domain under that directory?  You may have some UAC issues if that's the case.

Comment: Yes I am using Windows and what I have glassfish installed in the directory C: \ Program Files \ glassfish-3.1.2. And as checks for UAC problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the error persists after changing the port, what you should do is eliminate **domain.xml** is located in the installation directory + **glassfish \ domains \ domain1 \ config** and then delete all projects that no longer exist. If this project does not exists delete

```
<applications> 
    <Application context-root = "/ MyProject" location = "file :/ C :/ Users / Administrator / Documents / NetBeansProjects / MyProject / build / web /" name = "MyProject" directory-deployed = "true" object-type = "user"> 
      <property name="preserveAppScopedResources" value="true"> </ property> 
      <property name="appLocation" value="file:/C:/Users/Administrador/Documents/NetBeansProjects/MyProject/build/web/"> </ property> 
      <property name="defaultAppName" value="web"> </ property> 
      <property name="keepSessions" value="true"> </ property> 
      <module name="MyProject"> 
        <Engine sniffer="jpa"> </ engine> 
        <Engine sniffer="security"> </ engine> 
        <Engine sniffer="web"> </ engine> 
      </ Module> 
    </ Application>
```

Then remove from the Netbeans Glassfish server and add it again and ready for me it worked